# IPv6 IP addresses with Netty

Tags: java, netty, ipv6

I have a sandboxed interpreter in Java, and I'd like each separate instance of the interpreter to have its own public IPv6 IP address, including being able to bind the sub-1024 ports on those IP addresses. (If you have a whole IP address for yourself, you don't need to worry about port conflicts, right?)

I believe a single IP address per interpreter is more than enough. No need to give them whole /96 (definitely not whole /64) prefixes or something.

How can I dynamically allocate the IP addresses with Netty?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: This is asking more about OS administration than Netty.

Comment: @chrylis What do you mean? I need it to be portable. (That's why I'm using Java)

Comment: Configuring the underlying network stack isn't portable.

Comment: I'm not trying to configure the underlying network stack. I'm just trying to plug my virtual ethernet cable into the virtual ethernet port, so that I can run my own virtual switch. Is there any way at all I can get a virtual switch, Netty or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use plain java apis to find the IP addresses assigned to the machines and then bind those ip addresses to your instance. [Please refer to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

Comment: Ok, so I can list addresses. Can I allocate an IPv6 subnet?

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to the netty or any other networking framework/api. If you want to "allocate the **unique** IP address", I think you may migrate your application as a [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) in the kubernetes.  You'll allocate an unique IP address for each of your application/pod instance. At that way, "you don't need to worry about the port conflicts" with others who running at same box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).